# How do you detect if there is motion between frames using opencv without simply subtracting the frames?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a camera in a fixed position looking at a target and I want to detect whether someone walks in front of the target. The lighting in the scene can change so subtracting the new changed frame from the previous frame would therefore detect motion even though none has actually occurred. I have thought to compare the number of contours (obtained by using findContours() on a binary edge image obtained with canny and then getting size() of this) between the two frames as a big change here could denote movement while also being less sensitive to lighting changes, I am quite new to OpenCV and my implementations have not been successful so far. Is there a way I could make this work or will I have to just subtract the frames. I don't need to track the person, just detect whether they are in the scene.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit rusty but there are various ways to do this.

SIFT and SURF are very expensive operations, so I don't think you would want to use them.

There are a couple of 'background removal' methods.

1. Average removal: in this one you get the average of N frames, and consider it as BG. This is vulnerable to many things, light changes, shadow, moving object staying at a location for long time etc.
2. Gaussian Mixture Model: a bit more advanced than 1. Still vulnerable to a lot of things.
3. IncPCP (incremental principal component pursuit): I can't remember the algorithm totally but basic idea was they convert each frame to a sparse form, then extract the moving objects from sparse matrix.
4. Optical flow: you find the change across the temporal domain of a video. For example, you compare frame2 with frame1 block by block and tell the direction of change.
5. CNN based methods: I know there are a bunch of them, but I didn't really follow them. You might have to do some research. As far as I know, they often are better than the methods above.

Notice that, for a @30Fps, your code should complete in 33ms per frame, so it could be real time. You can find a lot of code available for this task.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of ways you could do this.

The first that comes to mind is doing a 2D FFT on the incoming images. Color shouldn't affect the FFT too much, but an object moving, entering/exiting a frame will.

The second is to use SIFT or SURF to generate a list of features in an image, you can insert these points into a map, sorted however you like, then do a set_difference between the last image you took, and the current image that you have. You could also use the FLANN functionality to compare the generated features.